# bash: identifying the first value list that also exists in another list

Tags: bash

I have been trying to come up with a nice way in BASH to find the first entry in list `A` that also exists in list `B`.  Where `A` and `B` are in separate files.

```
   A         B
1024dbeb  8e450d71
7e474d46  8e450d71
1126daeb  1124dae9
7e474d46  7e474d46
1124dae9  3217a53b
```

In the example above, `7e474d46` is the first entry in `A` also appearing in `B`, So I would return `7e474d46`.

**Note:** `A` can be millions of entries, and `B` can be around 300.

Comment: Is it a file that contains these entries? You haven't mentioned this anywhere. Both the answers here are based on the assumption that you're having these entries in a file. But seeing `millions of entries`  in your question is making me a bit skeptical about this assumption.

Comment: The file contains binary values as HEX ASCII of fixed width.   Those values are a subset of actual data.   The "A" files are 100+Megs and the "B" files are 1-ish Megs.  It's sensor data, so I'm looking for the first event.  They data is fixed width.

Comment: @sjsam I made the question clearer as there are two files.  I oversimplified things by trying to make the question tractable. :/

Comment: I have updated my answer to suit two files as inputs

Comment: @sjsam worked great.  I need to learn awk. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>awk</kbd> is your friend.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{if(a[$1]>=1){print $1;exit}}' file2 file1
7e474d46
```

---

<sup>**Note :** Check the [[ **previous version** ]](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44758571/3) of this answer too which assumed that values are listed in a single file as two columns. This one is wrote after you have clarified that values are fed as two files in [[ **this** ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758367/bash-identifying-the-first-value-list-that-also-exists-in-another-list/44758571#comment76499284_44758367) comment.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Though few points are not clear, like how about if a number in A list is coming 2 times or more?(IN your given example itself d46 comes 2 times). Considering that you need all the line numbers of list A which are present in List B, then following will help you in same.

```
awk '{col1[$1]=col1[$1]?col1[$1]","FNR:FNR;col2[$2];} END{for(i in col1){if(i in col2){print col1[i],i}}}'  Input_file
```

**OR(NON-one liner form of above solution)**

```
awk '{
        col1[$1]=col1[$1]?col1[$1]","FNR:FNR;
        col2[$2];
     }
        END{
                for(i in col1){
                                if(i in col2){
                                                print col1[i],i
                                             }
                              }
           }
    '   Input_file
```

Above code will provide following output.

```
3,5 7e474d46
6 1124dae9
```

creating array col1 here whose index is first field and array col2 whose index is $2. col1's value is current line's value and it will be concatenating it's own value too. Now in END section of awk traversing through col1 array and then checking if any value of col1 is present in array col2 too, if yes then printing col1's value and it's index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep, you can try this:

```
grep -m 1 -f B A
```